# Dynamically add to Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have need to dynamically (not manually edit models.py) alter/add/remove from a Django Model. Is this possible? Once the model is altered, will it persist? I then want to use South for running the database migration from the altered model.

Comment: Is http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html#accessing-the-orm this what I need?

Comment: Anything is possible, this would require reading in the file, removing the lines or adding the ones needed in the right class of the model - saving the file and running migrate - all of which are possible but the technical level would be moderate. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I think it would help if you told us what you're trying to accomplish.  There is probably a better way to do it than altering model definitions.

Comment: We need to do this because the business needs/wants the ability to add additional data to the application without a developer having to manually modify the project.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want your program to add and delete fields from the model?  That sounds like a bad idea.  That would imply that your database schema will change dynamically under program control, which would be very unusual indeed.  Think harder about what data you need to represent, and come up with a database schema that works for all of your data.

Or, change to a non-SQL database, which means avoiding South altogether.

Comment: Yes, this is what we want to do. There are a few users that want to be able to add data as needs arise. It doesn't seem all that unusual to me... plenty of apps allow this type of control, no?

Comment: Many apps allow this, but they don't do it by letting users change the schema of a relational database.  They do it by having a generic NAME, VALUE table, or by storing the data in a non-relational database.

Comment: I thought about having that sort of table. Adding a separate table from the already defined models might work, that has a name, value type structure.

Comment: My fear with a name,value table is the maintainability for the future.